# Global values inside template function not changing [c++]

Tags: c++, function, templates, variables, global

I need help with a project. Basically I need to measure the clock ticks for some sorting algorithms. Since they all use comparison and sometimes, swapping functions, I designed them to accept these as callback functions.

To measure the clock ticks I wrote:

```
static clock_t t1, total;

template<typename T>
bool less_default(T & left, T & right){
    t1 = clock(); 
    bool v = left < right; 
    t1 = clock() - t1;
    total += t1
    return v;
}
```

When I actually run the algorithms, neither total or t1 reflect any change whatsoever. As if the lines of code referring to them were never written.

nothing works. Not even an increment of a simple integer on function call.

Is it that static global variables can't be changed inside a template function?

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: are you calling from the same file? Is it in a .h file?

Comment: Consider changing that `static` to an `extern` and declaring **one** *real* set of variables in the `main()` source file (or some oher suitable location).

Comment: Consider to measure the comparison of a million of objects, not of one object. And please use something else but globals.

Comment: When T is a very large array and each element is compared I am convinced the ticks should be greater than 0. Yet this is not happening.

Comment: How do you know the ticks aren't greater than zero? You have multiple copies of the same value. Which one are you incrementing? Which one are you checking? Is it the same one? How do you know? Can you tie the function which increments with a function which prints the value, so that it's the same value?

Comment: The `clock()` function ticks *very* slowly. On my machine `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is 1000, indicating that it counts milliseconds. No operator takes *that* long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> nothing works. Not even an increment of a simple integer on function call.

I suspect that the following appears in a *header* file:

```
static clock_t t1, total;
```

If that's the case, each translation unit will get its own separate instance of the two variables (thanks to `static`).

To fix, change `static` to `extern` in the header, and add the following to the .cpp file:

```
clock_t t1, total;
```

---

**EDIT** Sample to follow that demonstrates this:

Per the OP's request, this is a short example that uses a template comparator and the recipe in this answer to declare and manage a running clock total.

**main.h**

```
#ifndef PROJMAIN_DEFINED
#define PROJMAIN_DEFINED

extern clock_t total;

template<typename T>
bool less_default(const T& left, const T& right)
{
    clock_t t1 = clock();
    bool res = (left < right);
    total += (clock() - t1);
    return res;
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include "main.h"
using namespace std;

clock_t total = 0;

int main()
{
    static const size_t N = 2048;
    vector<int> values;
    values.reserve(N);
    std::srand((unsigned)time(0));

    cout << "Generating..." << endl;
    generate_n(back_inserter(values), N, [](){ static int i=0; return ++i;});

    for (int i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
        random_shuffle(values.begin(), values.end());
        cout << "Sorting ..." << endl;
        total = 0;
        std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), less_default<int>);
        cout << "Finished! : Total = " << total << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
Generating...
Sorting ...
Finished! : Total = 13725
Sorting ...
Finished! : Total = 13393
Sorting ...
Finished! : Total = 15400
Sorting ...
Finished! : Total = 13830
Sorting ...
Finished! : Total = 15789
```

Comment: It does. However changing it to be a normal global variable also results in no change. And I can't put these in my cpp file because then the compiler compains that the values do not exist

Comment: @Yuma: That's a separate issue. You are trying to measure something that takes less than a single tick of the clock.

Comment: @Yuma honestly the way this is written it will take longer to take the *clock* measurement than to perform the actual eval being measured. so your numbers will be horribly inaccurate regardless.

Comment: No it isn't. Even when I force it by doing, say total += clock() just to see if anything would change.

Comment: @Yuma: Have you made the changes outlined in my answer?

Comment: Yes. To no avail I am afraid.

Comment: @Yuma I don't suppose you **debugged** this, and actually ensured your operator is even being *called* ?

Comment: Without this function working as intended, how do you suppose lists are being properly sorted. This is the only existing callback function I have made so far and is given to all of the sorting functions.

Comment: @Yuma so that would be.. no?

Comment: @WhozCraig What exactly do you mean when you say debugging. I have checked whether this particular operator and function are being called by changing the sign temporarily. No matter what I do total and t1 never change from 0.

Comment: @Yuma I mean ensure the actual *code* that updates your `total` (t1 can be local so I'm not sure why yours is also global) does so. I.e. a *breakpoint* on `total += t1`. I have a sample `quicksort()` algorithm  that I just retrofitted with your comparator paradigm, applying NPE's answer here, and it does *exactly* what it is supposed to. Following NPE's answer (except I moved t1 to be local for what should be obvious reasons) this *works*, inaccuracies and all. I'll post it if you want to try it on your rig as a separate project. its two short files. (main.h, main.cpp)

Comment: @Yuma and I hope your setup is single-threaded. As-written `t1` not being local will give utterly meaningless data in a multi-threaded execution when two threads are firing your comparator, one will stomp over the others t1 setting, and vice-versa, with each eval.

Comment: @WhozCraig That would be nice. I'm at my wits end.

Comment: Actually, let me move it to *this* answer, they should go together. (Hope thats ok, @NPE).

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug with how you are setting up the globals. (NPE's answer covers this.)

However, another thing to keep in mind is that you are trying to measure the performance of *a single comparison*. It depends on what `T` is, but for most simple types, this will be one or two CPU instructions, which is *far* too small to be measured accurately with a technique like this.

You would be much better off using a sampling profiler. With the code you have here, your instrumentation is much, much more expensive than the work being done, which makes the profiling data useless.

Comment: This is merely one exaple. I have used this in my swapping/exchange functions as well. Even when swapping a gigantic array, clock ticks refuse to becoming anything other than zero.

Comment: If you are using `std::swap` on a `std::vector`, the array size doesn't matter; the swap operation is just exchanging a few pointers (and is maybe tens of opcodes).